# SSH continuous deployment with self hosted Drone CI

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, drone.io

I just need a simple guide on how to setup SSH continuous deployment with a self hosted Drone CI. Is it possible to do that? I know that Drone.io offers continuous deployment in many ways (SSH, Heroku, AppEngine, Amazon S3 ...etc) but what about self hosted Drone CI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that self hosted Drone is awesome enough to have a Go plugin that supports Continuous Deployment. It's really simple as this:

```
deploy:
  bash:
    script:
      - bundle exec cap deploy:update
```